# Trigger java install using wix

Tags: java, wix

I am trying to trigger a java 8 install using a wix generated msi. I included once the offline installer and once the online installer and each time i get the same error "actual error code 1618". And the java install fails. If i do a standalone java install the install completes with no problems.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1618 is ERROR_INSTALL_ALREADY_ RUNNING.  Basically MSI enforces a system wide mutex that prevents two installations running at the same time.  One MSI cannot install another MSI.  You should have to create a bootstrapper / chainer ( WiX has one called Burn )  to install Java and then install your MSI.