# Trying to install JDK18.exe through WIX installer

Tags: java, windows-installer, wix3.6, silent-installer

I am trying to install JDK18.EXE through wix installer but its not working.We are not using bootstrap and calling from Binaryfile and Customaction its not working.

I tried after install finalize also getting the error.

```xml
<Binary Id="JDK18.exe" SourceFile="..\jdk-18_windows-x64_bin.msi"></Binary>
<CustomAction Id="InstallJDK" Impersonate="no" Execute="deferred" BinaryKey="JDK18.exe" ExeCommand="" Return="asyncWait"/>

<Custom Action="InstallJDK" After="InstallFiles">NOT Installed</Custom>
```

```
Line 10186: MSI (s) (DC:B0) [17:52:23:737]: Doing action: InstallJDK
Line 10187: Action 17:52:23: InstallJDK. Installing JDK,This might take a while
Line 10188: Action start 17:52:23: InstallJDK.
Line 10190: Action ended 17:52:27: InstallJDK. Return value 1.
Line 38286: MSI (s) (DC:B0) [17:53:13:158]: Executing op: ActionStart(Name=InstallJDK,Description=Installing JDK,This might take a while,)
Line 38287: Action 17:53:13: InstallJDK. Installing JDK,This might take a while
Line 38288: MSI (s) (DC:B0) [17:53:14:139]: Executing op: CustomActionSchedule(Action=InstallJDK,ActionType=3202,Source=BinaryData,Target="/qn" "/s",)
Line 38934: 1: InstallJDK 2: 1631
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Trigger java install using wix](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33394280/trigger-java-install-using-wix)

Comment: OP says it's after InstallFinalize so that should not be the issue. I think the issue is that you're trying to run the MSI directly. See if calling it with msiexec.exe with /i <pathToMSI> works better.